# How to get the Textboxes the same height (responsive)

Tags: html, css, slideshow

I copied/built this slideshow. Everything works out finde but i have one last issue and i dont know how to fix it. Is it possible to keep the colored textboxes the same height on every slide?

Thanks in advance!

```css
* {
  margin: 0%;
  padding: 0%;
}


/* Slider */

#slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.frame {
  width: 400%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation: slide 30s infinite;
  -moz-animation: slide 30s infinite;
  animation: slide 30s infinite;
}

.slide {
  width: 25%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slide p {
  color: #ffffff;
}

#image1,
#image2,
#image3,
#image4 {
  height: 550px;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
}

#content1,
#content2,
#content3,
#content4 {
  padding: 1rem 6rem;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

#content1 {
  background-color: #f85756;
}

#content2 {
  background-color: #46C6C1;
}

#content3 {
  background-color: #FF844B;
}

#content4 {
  background-color: #0D9E19;
}

#image1 {
  background-image: url(../img/fahrradrund_verkauf.png);
}

#image2 {
  background-image: url(../img/fahrradrund_werkstatt.png);
}

#image3 {
  background-image: url(../img/fahrradrund_lastenrad.png);
}

#image4 {
  background-image: url(../img/fahrradrund_kinderrad_abo.png);
}


/* Animation */

@-webkit-keyframes slide {
  0%,
  100% {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
  21% {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
  25% {
    margin-left: -100%;
  }
  46% {
    margin-left: -100%;
  }
  50% {
    margin-left: -200%;
  }
  71% {
    margin-left: -200%;
  }
  75% {
    margin-left: -300%;
  }
  96% {
    margin-left: -300%;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes slide {
  0%,
  100% {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
  21% {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
  25% {
    margin-left: -100%;
  }
  46% {
    margin-left: -100%;
  }
  50% {
    margin-left: -200%;
  }
  71% {
    margin-left: -200%;
  }
  75% {
    margin-left: -300%;
  }
  96% {
    margin-left: -300%;
  }
}

@keyframes slide {
  0%,
  100% {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
  21% {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
  25% {
    margin-left: -100%;
  }
  46% {
    margin-left: -100%;
  }
  50% {
    margin-left: -200%;
  }
  71% {
    margin-left: -200%;
  }
  75% {
    margin-left: -300%;
  }
  96% {
    margin-left: -300%;
  }
}


/* responsive */


/* 1000px */

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  #content1,
  #content2,
  #content3,
  #content4 {
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
  }
}


/* 675px */

@media only screen and (max-width: 675px) {
  #content1,
  #content2,
  #content3,
  #content4 {
    padding: 1rem 1rem;
  }
  #image1,
  #image2,
  #image3,
  #image4 {
    height: 350px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="slider">
  <div class="frame">
    <div class="slide">
      <a href="test.html">
        <div id="image1">
        </div>
        <div id="content1">
          <div class="content-txt">
            <h2>Exampletext</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <div class="legend"></div>
      <a href="test.html">
        <div id="image2">
        </div>
        <div id="content2">
          <div class="content-txt">
            <h2>Exampletext</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <div class="legend"></div>
      <a href="test.html">
        <div id="image3">
        </div>
        <div id="content3">
          <div class="content-txt">
            <h2>Exampletext</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <div class="legend"></div>
      <a href="test.html">
        <div id="image4">
        </div>
        <div id="content4">
          <div class="content-txt">
            <h2>Exampletext</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: pls add code in https://jsfiddle.net/ and we can have a look :)

Comment: Please don’t, we should try to have an [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the question itself, not elsewhere. “…Complete – Provide all parts someone else needs to reproduce your problem in the question itself”.
Instead, use a code snippet.